# Как в OpenGL указывать цвет не для каждой вершины, а сразу для всего треугольника?

Tags: c++, opengl

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы для отрисовки нескольких треугольников я мог писать не так:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    //   Position            Color
        -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
         0.0f, -0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
         0.0f,  0.2f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
         1.0f, -0.3f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f   
    };
```

А вот так:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // Color of triangle
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        // Positions
        -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,  
         0.0f, -0.0f, 0.0f, 
         0.0f,  0.2f, 0.0f,  

         // Color of triangle
         0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         // Positions
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 
         1.0f, -0.3f, 0.0f,  
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  
    };
```

Вершинный шейдер

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
out vec3 fcolor;

void main()
{
    fcolor = color;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Фрагментный шейдер

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 fcolor;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(fcolor, 1.0f);
}
```

VAO и VBO

```
GLuint VBO, VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: Вы просто не хотите дублировать цвет или есть какая то другая причина?

Comment: Не хочу дублировать цвет

Comment: можно попробовать использовать индексный буфер, тогда на каждую вершину нужно будет только индекс указать, а цвета будут хранится в отдельном массиве и дублировать не нужно будет. Но в любом случае, каждой вершине нужно так или иначе указать цвет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого следует переключиться на использование топологии точки и в качестве блока входящих данных подавать сразу данные всего треугольника. Причем тут еще можно сэкономить, не дублируя координату z, раз она (судя по примеру) совпадает у всех точек треугольника.

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
//  A             B            C            z     color
    -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f, -0.0f, 0.0f,  0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, -0.3f, 0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f   
    };
```

Затем распаковывать каждых такой блок в геометрическом шейдере в три вершины, подавая на выход готовый треугольник.